# How exactly Worksheet.Usedrange is calculated?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a document with a sheet, where the real used range is `A1:BJ36360`, but a property `UsedRange` returns a range with address `A1:BJ72724`. A range `A36361:BJ72724` is empty, there's no values, no formattings, and no formula is addressing any cell from it. I can do:

```
Range("A36361:BJ72724").Clear
Range("A36361:BJ72724").ClearFormat
Range("A36361:BJ72724").Clear<whatever the method with Clear at the beginning there is>
Range("A36361:BJ72724").Delete
```

But `UsedRange` remains the same `A1:BJ72724`. And if only I run:

```
Range("A36361:BJ72724").Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

then `UsedRange` returns the expected range `A1:BJ36360`.

What could be the reason of this behaviour? How exactly `UsedRange` is calculated?

---

p.s. Office 365, Excel version 16.0

Comment: yup that is a known issue.  Which is why using UsedRange to accurately find the last row or column is problematic and to be avoided.

Comment: I guess `UsedRange` was/is even calculated differently on different Excel versions. I remember saving the file was updating UsedRange, but on my current version (365) it is updated immediately when clearing the last used cell - at least for the small example I just did. Long story short: Don't use `UsedRange`. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba to see for alternatives

Comment: @FunThomas could it be that they finally fixed it?  I too cannot make it do what it did in previous versions.

Comment: Maybe. But I would not rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

I use this routine, based on info at https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

```
Sub sub1() ' demo the routines
  Dim zRow&, zCol&
  Call LastCellActive(zRow, zCol)
  Debug.Print zRow; zCol
End Sub

Sub LastCellActive(zRow&, zCol&) ' last row, col in Activesheet
  ' https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm
  On Error Resume Next ' zeros if blank sheet
  zRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
  zCol = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of why.  It only duplicates the answers given in the link provided in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba  Which if that was the answer to this question we would have closed as a duplicate.  The question is, "Why does UsedRange give the wrong extents?" and not, "How to find the last row and column?"